# How can I create a motion animation of a circle in swift

Tags: swift, xcode

so my Problem is, that I want to have a motion animation of a circle, which is moving from left to right. The circle is created like this:

```
let point = CGPoint.init(x: 10, y: 10)
let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: point, radius: CGFloat(20), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi * 2), clockwise: true)
let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
```

How do I create a motion animation of a circle like this?

Comment: What sort of “motion” do you want?

Comment: Just like the red rectangle here: https://medium.com/lattice-product-development/swift-animations-for-ios-10444cfaedbb

Comment: Well that tutorial tells you exactly how to do it.

Comment: To be honest, I don‘t understand how it works and if I implement it, I see many errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done moving animation on imageView, You can try on any View it will work.

```
  private func animate(_ image: UIImageView) {
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
            image.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: self.view.frame.width/2-10, y: 0)
        }) { (success: Bool) in
            image.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            self.animate(image) // imageAnime is outlet
            self.imageAnim.layer.removeAllAnimations() // if you want to remove animation after its done animating once
        }
    }
```

call this function Where you want your animation to be done